# Search C# DataTable for List of terms, then return row Id for the results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I'm new to using DataTables and am confused about why this does not work.

What I want to do is search the "text" column of all rows in the DataTable for any of the words listed in the "terms" (List).  If one of them is found, I want to add the Id of the row to another list, "resultIds" (List).

The three columns for the DataTable are created from a SQL result that has the following columns:

- Id - int, primary key, not nullable
- ParentId - int, default 0, not nullable
- Text - varchar(MAX), nullable

Can someone assist me with understanding why this doesn't work?

<strike>The error is "Error 4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'".</strike>

**Edit:**  Now I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error" when it tries to add the Id to the list.

```
    public ActionResult Search(MyModel model)
    {
        // This string gets passed in as part of the Model from the View
        string delimitedText = model.text.Replace(" ", ",");

        // Convert the comma delimited string into a List<>.
        List<string> terms = delimitedText.Split(',').ToList();

        // List<> to hold all Ids for matched DataTable rows
        List<int> resultIds = null;

        // Populate the DataTable with SQL result set
        DataTable dt = TableDAO.Search();

        // For each term in the "terms" List<>
        foreach (string term in terms)
        {
            // Search each DataRow in the DataTable
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                // If the DataRow's column "text" contains the current term in the "terms" List<>...
                if (dr["text"].ToString().Contains(term))
                {

                    // Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", happens with resultIds.Add((int)dr["id"]); as well.
                    resultIds.Add((int)dr.ItemArray[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", resultIds);
    }
```

Comment: What line is the error pointing to?

Comment: It's pointing to the line with >> resultIds.Add(dr["id"]);

Comment: dr["id"] returns an object and your resultIds are expecting an int value.  Cast dr["id"] to int.

Comment: You either need to cast to `int`, or convert to `int` depending on what type you put in the id column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resultIds.Add(dr["id"])` is a dynamic expression and in the compile time it considered as object so you have to convert it as follows

```
resultIds.Add(int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString()));
```

Comment: After updating the code with the cast, it gives it throws a NullReferenceException error stating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", even if i use dr.ItemArray[0] instead of dr["id"].  Any ideas?

Comment: you have created **resultIds** as a null list,so the list is a null object. you have to create it like this: ` List<int> resultIds =new List<int>()`;

Comment: try it and give me a feedback

Comment: Doh!  Thank you for pointing that out to me.  You, sir, are both a gentleman and a scholar.  Cheers!